# Can I mock out library code with a nested interface?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, interface

I am trying to mock a 3rd party library in a test in my go code. But I cannot compile the approach that I have taken. Is there any way to make this work, or another approach I can take if I want to mock the result of `T2.M2`?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Two types in a library that I dont have control over
type T1 struct {}
func (T1) M1() T2 {
    return T2{}
}
type T2 struct {}
func (T2) M2() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}

// I created these interfaces in order to assign an instance of T1 
// to a variable of type I1 so that I can mock the behavior of T2.M2()
// problem is that this doesn't compile.
type I1 interface {
    M1() I2
}
type I2 interface {
    M2() // I want to mock this method
}

// Then I would be able to create a mock
type Mock1 struct {}
func (Mock1) M1() I2 {
    return Mock2{}
}
type Mock2 struct {}
func (Mock2) M2() {
    fmt.Println("HELLO WORLD")
}

func main() {
    var i1 I1
    i1 = T1{}
    i1.M1().M2()
    i1 = Mock1{}
    i1.M1().M2()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/sv-Uuuke1dr

Comment: You can't mock T2.M2() unless the context you're mocking it uses it via an interface. If the context uses it as a struct, then your best option is to fill out a mock instance of T2{}.

Comment: So there is no way to do the assignment
`var i1 I1 = T1{}`?

Comment: No, because `T1` doesn't satisfy the contract in `I1` (the signatures of `T1.M1` and `I1.M1` do not match).

Comment: I would look closely at how this library's own tests are written; usually a well-tested library also makes code using it easily testable. If the library is not well-tested, I would look for alternatives - not just because your testing will be difficult, but because using a library without good tests of its own is a high-risk proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your dependency in structs embedding dependent types:

```golang
// answer wrap your dependency
type Ta1 struct {
  T1
}
func (Ta1) M1() I2 {
    return Ta2{}
}
type Ta2 struct {
   T2
}
```

Then it will work:

```golang
func main() {
    var i1 I1
    i1 = Ta1{}
    i1.M1().M2()
    i1 = Mock1{}
    i1.M1().M2()
}
```

Try on https://play.golang.org/p/aHr78dY_c9a

Comment: This will only work if your tests use Ta1 and Ta2, or the interfaces I1 and I2. It will not work if you pass these new types to the library functions that use T1 and T2.

Comment: @bserdar I agree. But if you mock this library and introduce your own interfaces then there won't be code using T1 and T2 directly. But in case that some consumer requires `struct T1` then I don't think there is any solution. `Accept interfaces` they say.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot mock structs in Go. Only interfaces.

Comment: That's why the first step is to create an interface mimicking dependency (or part of it).