# Can't mock struct for testing

Tags: go

Trying to mock struct for testing. But following code has an error:

```
./test.go:32:17: cannot use NewClass() (type *Class) as type mockClass in return argument:
    *Class does not implement mockClass (wrong type for Query method)
        have Query() *Iterator
        want Query() mockIterator
```

Why I can't do that?

```
func NewClass() *Class {
    return &Class{}
}

type Class struct{}

func (Class) Query() *Iterator {
    return &Iterator{}
}

type Iterator struct{}

func (Iterator) Next() error {
    return nil
}

type mockClass interface {
    Query() mockIterator
}

type mockIterator interface {
    Next() error
}

var newMock = func() mockClass {
    return NewClass()
}
```

In the test I want to assign to `newMock` something like:

```
newMock = funcr() mockClass {
    return &fakeClass{}
}
```

The structs `Class` and `Iterator` are not under my control. Those structs come from external library.

Comment: *"Why I can't do that?"* For a type to implement an interface, its methods MUST match the methods of the interface **verbatim**. `Query() *Iterator` and `Query() mockIterator` do not match, even if the `*Iterator` type implements the `mockIterator` interface it doesn't matter, those two methods are simply not the same and therefore `Class` *does not implement* `mockClass`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an interface that expresses business logic that your component needs. Do not use any 3rd party types.
2. Use that interface in your business logic.
3. Create an implementation of this interface wrapping 3rd party library and pass it to your component in `main.go`, which is a good place to wire/inject various system components.

That way you can easily mock **your** interface and change the implementation for another if one day you decide not to use this 3rd party library.

If for some reason you are tied to this library and there is no way to create an interface not referencing 3rd party types, then have a look at the [Can I mock out library code with a nested interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013533/can-i-mock-out-library-code-with-a-nested-interface/58014505#58014505)